# How do I get rows from one table that do not exist in another table

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I am building a Spring boot application with the following table DDLs

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QUESTIONS(
   question_id bigint auto_increment,
   question_text varchar(256),
   answer boolean, primary key(question_id)
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS question_id_index on Questions(question_id);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QuizQuestions(
    id bigint auto_increment,
    quiz_id varchar(10),
    question_id bigint,
    FOREIGN KEY(quiz_id) REFERENCES Quiz(quiz_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(question_id) REFERENCES Questions(question_id)
)
```

I need to write a sql query such that

1) if there is at least one row which exists in `QuizQuestions` table for `quiz_id` , then I need to return all the `question_id` entries from `Questions` table that don't exist in `QuizQuestions` table.

2) If there aren't any rows for a specific quiz id in `QuizQuestions` table, then I want to return all rows from `Questions` table.

My sample data is as follows

```
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES (1, 'Is 2016 a leap year?', TRUE);
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES(2, 'Is Sunday a weekday?', FALSE);
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES(3, 'Is August the 8th month?', TRUE);
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES(4, 'Is July 25 independence day of United States of America?', FALSE);
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES(5, 'Does January have 31 days in a month?', TRUE);
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES(6, 'Does UK have a monarchy?', TRUE);
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES(7, 'Does Lebron play football?', FALSE);
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES(8, 'Is Los Angeles in New York state?', FALSE);
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES(9, 'Is Canada to the north of United States?', TRUE);
INSERT INTO Questions(question_id, question_text, answer) VALUES(10, 'Does November have 30 days in a month?', TRUE);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO QuizQuestions(quiz_id, question_id) VALUES('ABCDE12345', 5);
```

So if I query for `quiz_id = ABCDE12345`, I want to return all rows from `Questions` except the entry for `question_id=5` because that already exists in `QuizQuestions` table.

If I were to query for any other quiz id that does not exist in `QuizQuestions` table, then I want to return all entries from `Question` table.  This is amy sample query

```
SELECT q.question_id, q.question_text, q.answer FROM Questions q
LEFT JOIN QuizQuestions qq ON q.question_id = qq.question_id WHERE 
qq.quiz_id = ?
```

and

```
SELECT q.question_id, q.question_text, q.answer FROM Questions q 
LEFT JOIN QuizQuestions qq ON 
q.question_id = qq.question_id WHERE q.question_id NOT IN 
(SELECT qq.question_id FROM Questions WHERE qq.quiz_id = ?)
```

I have tried every possible query that I can think of, but I have not been able to find an output.

**UPDATE**

This is the code that I am using to query the database. The collection output is always empty.

```
public QuizQuestion fetchUniqueQuizQuestion(String quizId) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SELECT q.question_id, q.question_text, q.answer FROM Questions q ");
    sb.append("WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM QuizQuestions WHERE question_id = q.question_id ");
    sb.append(" AND quiz_id = ?) ");
    sb.append("OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM QuizQuestions WHERE quiz_id = ?)");
    List<QuizQuestion> questions = 
        this.jdbcTemplate.query(
            sb.toString(), new Object[] {quizId, quizId}, new RowMapper<QuizQuestion>() {

          @Override
          public QuizQuestion mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            QuizQuestion qq = new QuizQuestion();
            qq.setQuestionId(rs.getInt("question_id"));
            qq.setQuizId(quizId);
            qq.setAnswer(rs.getBoolean("answer"));
            qq.setDescription(rs.getString("question_text"));
            return qq;
          }
        });
    Collections.shuffle(questions);
    return questions.isEmpty() ? null : questions.get(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT q.question_id, q.question_text, q.answer 
FROM Questions q
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM QuizQuestions 
        WHERE question_id = q.question_id
            AND
            quiz_id = 'the_quiz_id'
    )
    OR 
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM QuizQuestions 
        WHERE quiz_id = 'the_quiz_id'
    )
```

Comment: I don't understand the query. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: The first NOT EXISTS returns true if the question does not match a QuizQuestion for the specified quiz_id.
The second NOT EXISTS returns true if there are no QuizQuestions for the specified quiz_id

Comment: I ran the query in testing mode, but it does not work for me.

Comment: @Kartik - "does not work" is not an adequate description. Be more specific. Do you get an error? If so, what is it? Do you get the wrong result? If so, what do you get vs. what you expect? You probably should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47613848/edit) to provide additional information.

Comment: Hi, The result set does not return any response. I get an empty list. Updated my post.

Comment: Hi @Kartik, I have replicated this solution in my own SQL database and it's returning the correct results. Can you try executing the SQL query outside of your code?

Comment: Hi, Chris, Your suggestion worked. It was a data issue.